# Sign up/in partials

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I currently have two partials that I use for signing up and signing in. The code is essentially the same in both except for different images to represent sign up/in via Facebook/Twitter.

_sign_in_via.html.erb looks as follows:

```html
<div class="sign-up-via-links">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>
                <%= link_to(image_tag("fb_sign_in.png"), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), :class => "sign-in-image") %>
            </p>
            <p>
                <%= link_to(image_tag("tw_sign_in.png"), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter), :class => "sign-in-image") %>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

_sign_in_via.html.erb looks like so:

```html
<div class="sign-up-via-links">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>
                <%= link_to(image_tag("fb_sign_up.png"), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), :class => "sign-in-image") %>
            </p>
            <p>
                <%= link_to(image_tag("tw_sign_up.png"), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter), :class => "sign-in-image") %>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the code in these two partials is exactly the same apart from different images in the `link_to` tags. Is there any way these two partials can be refactored to better stick to the DRY principle?

Comment: Welcome SoSimple. Is this a stub? I see a ruby tag, but don't immediately see where the Ruby code.

Comment: @Legato Thank you. Yeah kind of. I wasn't 100% sure about tags. I'm using partials and ruby on rails, and I have a feeling ruby code will be the answer to making the current code more efficient but I'm not experienced enough with RoR yet to know for sure. I can remove the tag if it's misplaced/misleading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, but I don't recommend it unless you have a lot more identical examples. You could move both the hash and the `link_to` into [helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html), but I think that amount of indirection doesn't make things any clearer.

```
<div class="sign-up-via-links">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <% { facebook: 'fb_sign_up.png', twitter: 'tw_sign_up.png' }.each do |service, image| %>
        <p>
          <%= link_to(image_tag(image), user_omniauth_authorize_path(service), class: 'sign-in-image') %>
        </p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that the Ruby (and ERB) [standard](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#spaces-indentation) for indentation is two.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @dankohn. Your suggestion works fine and while you were also right in  that it isn't much clearer than having two partials - at least now I only have the one view file. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You know you *could* thank him a "lot" by upvoting too in addition to accept :p